# char comparison in Java

Tags: java, char, comparison

```
class Tryit {   
  public static void main(String args[])   
    throws java.io.IOException { 

    char ch, answer; 

    System.out.println("Please Enter a Secret Character for another user to guess."); 
    answer = (char) System.in.read(); 

    System.out.println("There is a Secret character for you...Can you guess it: \n"); 
    ch = (char) System.in.read(); // read a char from the keyboard 


    if(ch == answer) 

    {   
    System.out.println("** Right **"); 
    }
    else 
    {
    System.out.println("** Try Again **"); 
    }
  }   
}
```

i am trying to compare ch and answer variables but its not working, where i did the mistake. Help

Comment: contentEquals? char is primitive can use ==

Comment: What do you think `read` returns? Why do you think so?

Comment: `read` will also get the new line char `'\n'`. This is what you are comparing

Comment: I'd recommend using a `BufferedReader` with a `InputStreamReader` or a `Scanner` for reading input

Comment: Suppose Person "A" will type a secret character for another person "B" to guess what did he type for him to guess.... Just trying to check how 2 characters could be compared in java.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scanner... it's easy

Then just compare with ==, added while loop for kicks

```
class Tryit {   
      public static void main(String args[])   
        throws java.io.IOException { 

        char ch, answer; 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
         while(true) {
        System.out.println("Please Enter a Secret Character for another user to guess."); 
        answer = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println("There is a Secret character for you...Can you guess it: \n"); 
        ch = scanner.next().charAt(0); 

           if(ch == answer)    
           {   
            System.out.println("** Right **"); 
           }
           else 
          {
          System.out.println("** Try Again **"); 
          } 
        }
      }   
    }
```

Comment: Ya Wang, the code you provide is producing this error..........



Tryit2.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Tryit2
Tryit2.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                              ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Tryit2
2 errors

Comment: I'd suggest using a modern IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans. When you pasted `Scanner` in, it would have underlined it in red showing that it didn't recognize it, giving you the option to import it.